# Angular.js - create url using $location service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, location-href

Is there a way to do it?

If the current url is say..

`/table?sort=activity` and I wanted to update it right away, I'd do

`$location.url(null, {sort: 'something'})`

but what if I wanted to get back the updated url `/table?sort=something` without updating it?

All the `$location` functions seems to change the url right away when used with parameters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness thought I'd share this SO question. The question and answers are old but there's a good chance the answer still applies.

[How to programmatically create URLs with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808779/how-to-programatically-create-urls-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `$location.search()`

It would look something like this:

```
$location.search({sort: 'something'});
```

**Update based on comments**

According to [the Developers Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location), you can use the following to read the URL:

```
$location.absUrl();
```

To read the hash:

```
$location.path();
```

To read the query params:

```
$location.search();
```

Comment: That's not gonna work, it's gonna change the url, I only need it to return the changed url as a string..

Comment: If you just need to read it, you could use $location.path() or $location.url() without any arguments. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I guess you are looking for $location.absUrl();

Comment: Not really either :) I'm looking for something that's gonna "compile" the url for me, exactly what `$location.search({sort: 'something'})` does, but instead of directly changing the url, I just want it to return the url as a string.. any clearer now?

Comment: If I get you right, you need a URL builder functionality. not actually changing the URL but constructing a new one. Maybe this SO answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12896408/36546